# Avoid Confirm Form Resubmission for a search form

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, post

I have a complicated form for searching organisations in a MVC application.
The form is submitted using POST and returns a list of links.
The user is able to click on those links but when he tries to use the back button the "Confirm Form Resubmission" warning is shown.
Is there any solution to avoid this without using GET for posting the form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there isn't. Most search forms use GET anyway, so you can link to search results.